# change cursor to pointer on the icon for bootstrap has feedback input

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to get the cursor to be a pointer when I hover over the icon in the input.

here is the fiddle.   http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2758/

```
<div class=col-sm-4 style="padding-top: 50px;">
  <div class="form-group  has-feedback" style="pointer-events: initial !important;">
    <input type="text" style="pointer-events: initial !important;" class="form-control" ng-model="newItem">
    <span class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg text-info" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                                </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't even seem to get it to work with jquery

```
     $('.form-control-feedback').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        }

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet has the following rule which applies to the `<span>` enclosing the icon:

```
.form-control-feedback {
    /* ... */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You'll need to remove, modify, or override that rule to get the cursor to change.